# Getting "chunk write below min size" when trying to write to Google Cloud using gcsfs

Tags: dask

I have a script which uses `gcsfs` to write data to Google Cloud. Most of the time it works, but fairly regularly I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Non-final chunk write below min size.
```

This error seems to come from `GCSFile._upload_chunk`.

I can't really find anything in the docs that explains what might be going wrong here. I read [this thread](https://github.com/dask/gcsfs/issues/237)  which suggests it might be related to how the data is committed (should I disable autocommit?) but I'm not sure it's entirely relevant. I read through the source of that function but that didn't help too much either. Would appreciate any guidance!

My code looks like this:

```
with gcs.open(file_path, mode='w') as f:
    f.write('\n'.join(output_data))
```

`output_data` here is a list of strings. `gcs` is an instance of `gcsfs.GCSFileSystem`.

Comment: Can you detail "regularly". A traceback would be good; and also, you might want to install from master and enable logging by setting the environment variable GCSFS_DEBUG=1.

Comment: If you can come up with a self-contained and complete example of the problem, this can be posted as a bug on github

Comment: Thanks! I'll try to narrow it down, and get extra logging. So far it seems like it happens on certain files and not others, probably somewhere between 1% and 20% of files I'm trying to write. Will try to identify a specific file and simplify it/remove anything confidential so I can share the data.

Comment: Hi @mdurant - this issue disappeared when I ran the master branch. Then I realised I had still been running 0.6.0 of gcsfs, and just upgrading to 0.7.0 solved it. Thanks and apologies!

Answer (score 1):

This issue apparently no longer happens in v0.7.0. Anyone facing it should upgrade.